# Dynamic Shortcuts to open Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, dynamic, shortcut

Hi I'm developing an application that has 2 types of user: Admin and normal user; The admin obviously has more actions than the normal user, so I need to use dynamic Shortcuts, depending on the user the Shortcuts are created.

At this point everything is already codified and working. However, at the time of assigning an `Intent`, even to the `MainActivity` I receive an error.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.motusk.Monit", "com.motusk.Monit.activity.MainActivity"));

shortcut.add(new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "ub")
   .setShortLabel("Location")
   .setLongLabel("Location")
   .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.bg))
   .setIntent(intent)
   .build());
```

I also tried with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

But, in both I get the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.motusk.Monit/com.motusk.Monit.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: intent's action must be set

In what I need help with is:

1) How to create a correct `Intent` to the `MainActivity`?

2) How to know which shortcut was pressed? (The process of depending on which shortcut was pressed to open a certain `Fragment` will be performed in the `MainActivity`, that's why I need to know which Shortcut was pressed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the error message, your Intent must set an action with [setAction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String)):

```
intent.setAction("LOCATION_SHORTCUT");
```

You can then check the action in your Activity:

```
String action = getIntent() != null ? getIntent().getAction() : null;
if ("LOCATION_SHORTCUT".equals(action)) {
  // Show the correct fragment
}
```